# Which version of Blender can I use with an i3 and Windows 7?

Tags: versions, compatibility

I wanted to know which version of blender I can use with an Intel i3 and a standard visual graphics card of intel. The laptop is from 2013 with Windows 7 and I can't get a newer one.

Comment: The minimum requirements for Blender are documented [here](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). Blender 2.79b will work most likely, depending on the specific hardware you may even be able to run later versions. The GPU and driver version are the most crucial parts of the minimum requirements.

Comment: New versions is more optimized, so download the latest. On weak computer you just will be work slow, but it does not mean that program will crashed

Answer (score 1):

Start always with the latest version.

If that doesn't work then downgrade to an older one.

2.79 will work with most old and humble computers.

2.8 needs a bit more robust hardware (specially a good GPU).B

But the best way to know is to try it out.